# Is it possible to install timezone support in ClearDB?

Tags: mysql, heroku, timezone, chartkick, cleardb

I am trying to get **ChartKick** to work on my application on **Heroku**. I was able to setup and install timezone support on my local machine (thus resulting in ChartKick working perfectly).

However, on Heroku I am getting an error which basically is telling me to install timezone support for the database.

This is the error:

> 2018-04-16T10:44:43.215679+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [d7bfe4e4-bb80-48a8-aa34-b29e2db1b9c8]   [1m[35m (77.2ms)[0m 
>   [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all,
>   CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', 'Etc/UTC'),
>   '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), 'Etc/UTC', '+00:00') AS
>   convert_tz_date_format_convert_tz_created_at_00_00_etc_utc_y_m_d_00_00_00_etc_utc_00_00
>   FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`reader_id` = 5 AND
>   `orders`.`category_id` = 2 AND (created_at IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY
>   CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', 'Etc/UTC'),
>   '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), 'Etc/UTC', '+00:00') ORDER BY
>   `orders`.`created_at` ASC[0m 2018-04-16T10:44:43.217503+00:00
>   app[web.1]: [d7bfe4e4-bb80-48a8-aa34-b29e2db1b9c8]   Rendered
>   statistics/preferences.html.erb within layouts/application (91.5ms)
>   2018-04-16T10:44:43.217736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [d7bfe4e4-bb80-48a8-aa34-b29e2db1b9c8] Completed 500 Internal Server
>   Error in 128ms (ActiveRecord: 101.5ms)
>   2018-04-16T10:44:43.222450+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [d7bfe4e4-bb80-48a8-aa34-b29e2db1b9c8]
>   2018-04-16T10:44:43.222565+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [d7bfe4e4-bb80-48a8-aa34-b29e2db1b9c8] ActionView::Template::Error (Be
>   sure to install time zone support -
>   https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#for-mysql):
>   2018-04-16T10:44:43.222950+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [d7bfe4e4-bb80-48a8-aa34-b29e2db1b9c8]

I am using **ClearDB (MySQL)**, currently have access to it through my terminal, as well as SequelPro.
Please help me to get this work.

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with Heroku.

Comment: I had the same error on my local machine. I was able to sort it by adding  the files contained in "timezone_2018d_posix" (which I got from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html) to my mysql's installation folder (/usr/local/bin/). I've had the error on two of my local machines, and I always sorted it by adding those files. Now the problem is that I can't add those files to ClearDB (or maybe I don't know how). If there was a way to add them to clearDB then I would definitely try that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb/topics/are_time_zones_supported), time zones are only supported on dedicated systems with ClearDB.